# How to get a LONG_MAX octal value

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to print out the octal value of LONG_MAX (contained in limits.h) with this recursive function:

```
void    ft_get_nbr_base(long int nb, char *base, int i)
{
    int     size_base;
    int     size_nb;
    char *str;
    size_base = ft_strlen(base);
    if (nb >= size_base)
        ft_get_nbr_base(nb / size_base, base, i);
    if (i == 1)
        ft_putchar(base[(long int)(nb % size_base)]);
    if (i == 2)
        ft_putchar(ft_toupper(base[(long int)(nb % size_base)]));
}
```

So I call it like this : ft_get_nbr_base(LONG_MAX, "01234567", 1);

The result is : 777777777777777777777
Whereas when I do printf("%o", LONG_MAX) I get `37777777777`. Can you explain me how to get the same result as printf and why it shows this difference ? Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I am recoding the printf function

Comment: The code `printf("%o", LONG_MAX)` should have generated a warning from the compiler.

Comment: Note: The cast `(long int)` in `base[(long int)(nb % size_base)]` serves no useful purpose.  Use `base[(size_t) (nb % size_base)]`, else negative numbers may be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
fprintf(stdout, "%lo\n", LONG_MAX);
```

Since it's `long int` you need the `"l"` modifier, the compiler warns about this and it's very clear in any [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) manual.

Comment: Thank you I understand the problem now, so the fact that printf("%o", LONG_MAX) is giving 37777777777 can be called an "undefined behavior"?

Comment: Indeed, passing the incorrect type for a given specifier to `printf()` is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: So I guess for my printf I have to make this special case writing this particular false statement... Thks